# RecyclerView Add and delete items

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-recyclerview

My Recyclerview is filled by a cursor.. however i haven't found out a way to implement add or delete items from the recyclerview so far

Here's my Adapter class :

```
class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.ViewHolder> {


        Cursor curs;
        Context ctx;
        ViewHolder vh;
        CardView v;


        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView Note_Title, Note_Text;
            public RelativeLayout RLNote;

            public ViewHolder(CardView v) {
                super(v);
                Note_Title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                Note_Text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
                RLNote = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.note_background);
            }
        }

        public NotesAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            ctx = context;
            curs = c;
        }

        @Override
        public NotesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                int viewType) {
            v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.notes_fragment_custom, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            curs.moveToPosition(position);

            holder.Note_Title.setText(curs.getString(curs
                    .getColumnIndex(MiroDatabase.KEY_NOTES_TITLE)));

                holder.Note_Text.setText(curs.getString(curs
                        .getColumnIndex(MiroDatabase.KEY_NOTES_TEXT)));


        }

        public int getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.getItemId(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return curs.getCount();
        }
    }

}
```

Just like any recyclerview adapter class, but coupled with a cursor...

i didn't find on google any results for this

Hope you help! Thanks :)

Comment: RecyclerView is not made to work with cursors really. With a cursor you have to requery after data changes. You are going to have to turn that curso into an arraylist when you query then keep track of what changed when you requery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity you can :

```
TheDatabase MD;
NotesAdapter AA;
MD.close();
MD.open();
AA.ChangeCursor(c);
AA.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And in NotesAdapter class, add the function :

```
public void ChangeCursor(Cursor c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    curs = c;
}
```